Keyerror while accessing environment variable in AKS pod
My Python script uses environment variables, the environment variables are set by Azure configmap, and they are accessible from pod command prompt. They are also available to Python when I run manually on pod command line, but the environment variables are available when the program runs on crontab schedule. It fails with the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/fraudblk.py", line 6, in <module>
    from someLib import SomeFunc
  File "/app/someLib .py", line 920, in <module>
    userName = os.environ["CSI_USER"]
               ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 714, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'CSI_USER'

Tried with Python 3.7.

The thing with crontab is that you need to be 100% sure that the environment variables are there.  It doesn't seem that the required env vars are available in a crontab env.










printenv > /tmp/env.log
















. /proc/1/environ && /usr/bin/python3 /app/fraudblk.py









try this please

The main reason you are encountering a KeyError for environment variables in a crontab schedule is that crontab doesn't inherit environment variables in the same way a shell session or a running application does. This means that while the variables are available when you run the Python script manually, they aren't available by default when the script runs via crontab. To solve this issue, you need to ensure that crontab has access to the environment variables set by the ConfigMap.
Workaround -
Manually Set the Environment Variables in Crontab
kubectl exec -it <podname> -- /bin/bash
printenv | grep CSI

Copy the relevant environment variables (CSI_USER, CSI_PASS) into your crontab
* * * * * CSI_USER=my-user CSI_PASS=my-pass /usr/bin/python3 /app/fraudblk.py >> /tmp/output.log 2>&1

This explicitly sets the environment variables before running the script in crontab.
This is the easiest way. However, there are other two ways as well. If you want, you can check them out-
One is to source environment variables from /proc/1/environ in the crontab entry
* * * * * . /proc/1/environ && /usr/bin/python3 /app/fraudblk.py >> /tmp/output.log 2>&1

and another one is to create a script that sources environment variables and runs the Python script, then run this script via crontab
Example-
#!/bin/bash
. /proc/1/environ
/usr/bin/python3 /app/fraudblk.py

save and make it executable
chmod +x run_script.sh


Modify the crontab entry to run this script
* * * * * /app/run_script.sh >> /tmp/output.log 2>&1


Checkout this doc

Bhupal.Bobbadi hope this resolved your issue.
